# Image size mismatch between C and GO

Tags: c, image, go

Reading an image and counting the size of it's bytes yields different results in C vs. Go:

Using the same image, here's my readFile function in c:

```
FILE *inputFile = fopen(inputFilename, "rb");
if (inputFile == NULL)
{
    printf("cannot open file %s", inputFilename);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(inputFile);
    rewind(inputFile);
    return(fsize);
}
```

In Go, the same image:

```
// requests the same image as above
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

resp, _ := client.Do(req)

// Read the image into memory and set up the bytes buffer
img, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

size := len(img)
fmt.Println("%s\n", size)
return size
```

The C length of image is: 2275674
In Go, the size is: 1901248

Comment: I have no idea what `GO` is, but I would guess, that the `imgeProvider` thing is returning the image data stripped of all of the metadata, while C is not.

Comment: Agreed with @EugeneSh. The Go code does not look like a simple file-access. You are likely comparing apples with oranges. Note: `return` is not a function and you should not parenthetise the expression.

Comment: You never ever ran the Go code you sowed. It doesn't even compile. And wrapping img in a `bytes.Buffer` is complete useless if you want to know `len(img)`.

Comment: Simply check the size in your filemanager or with `ls -l`.

Comment: updated code sample, thanks @Volker.

Comment: I was wondering if I could get that same number as fseek is returning given the go code (sorry for the poorly written question). Is my only option to convert that image to ppm and read it that way?

Comment: You need to tell us what that `imageProvider.Get()` call actually does.

Comment: @bigthyme: file access in Go is works the same way. You can get the same value by reading, or seeking in the same file. We have no idea what `imageProvider` is doing between you and the file.

Comment: Remove the abstracted code. Thanks @JimB. I don't want to have to write the file upon getting the request just to get the size if at all possible.

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges. The C code reads a file from the filesystem while to Go code measures the length of a HTTP request body. Maybe the body is gziped? Or these are simply two different files. Read the same file from the FS, once with C, once with Go and don't try to be clever and you'll see the same size.

Answer (score -3):

In C, you're reading the raw file. It is not being interpreted as an image file, just a collection of bytes.

In Go (I'm not actually familiar), it appears you're using an image loader, which WOULD interpret the data as an image, decode it (decompress it if it's compressed), giving the size of the DECODED image.

The two would often differ (probably always except for some raw image types).

Comment: No, that is not the reason. _Decode_ images are basically just `width * height * bitdepth` large but you _cannot_ measure that size with the Gode shown.

Comment: The C code is examining the size of the file. Depending on the type of image, that may not in any way represent a size representative of width * height * bitdepth.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I was talking only about the Go code where you have a `[]byte` representing the encoded (jpeg, gif, png ...) image or a decoded pixel representation which is w * h * d bytes (+some metadata) or an abstract Image interface.